# How to allow all EC2 instances attached to a single SecurityGroup to talk to each other using their ElasticIPs instead of their PrivateIPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

What should be the appropriate security group rules to allow all EC2 instances attached to a single SecurityGroup to talk to each other using their ElasticIPs instead of their PrivateIPs

[image]

***ILLUSTRATING THE DIAGRAM ABOVE*** I have a single Public Subnet in a AmazonVPC. The subnet has 3 to many more EC2 instances: DevOps instance, PHP instance, Python instance, and several others. The DevOps instances is attached to 2 security groups SG1 & SG2. The PHP/Python instances are attached to only 1 security group SG2. Given the SG1 & SG2 rules shown in the table: the DevOps instance can be accessed from the world via SSH port:22 only; the PHP/Python instances can be accessed from the world via HTTP port:80 only; all ports in all the DevOps/PHP/Python instances can be accessed from all EC2 instances that are attached to the same security group only.

**USE CASE:** I would like to SSH into the DevOps instance from the internet using its ElasticIP 9.8.7.1. Then from the DevOps instance i would like to SSH into PHP/Python instance using their ElasticIPs 9.8.7.2 / 9.8.7.3 (not using their PrivateIPs). Also, my PHP app should be able to talk to the Python app via ElasticIP and vice versa - because the ElasticIPs are what we have in our source codes of the apps.

***PROBLEM1:*** Given the security group rules shown in the table, currently i am able to SSH from DevOps instance to PHP/Python instances by using their PrivateIPs only and not by using their ElasticIPs.

***PROBLEM2:*** My PHP/Python instances are also not able to communicate with each other via their ElasticIPs.

***CONSTRAINT:*** We regularly launch new instances for our PHP/Python apps from new/updated AMIs. Every time we launch a new instance, the PrivateIP changes. But I need to perform regular communication via something which does not change (i.e. the ElasticIP). We keep a ~/.ssh/config file in the DevOps instance so that doing SSH into the app instances are easy. In the ssh config file we have kept ElasticIPs as the IP address for our PHP/Python/Other instances. It's not possible to change the IP address in the ssh config file to a new PrivateIP address every time an app instance is replaced by a new one.

Comment: you can explicitly add inbound rules for SG2 like: 
1) AllPorts EIP1
2) AllPorts EIP2

Comment: I thought of that actually. That will definitely work. But it feels kind of redundant and inefficient. Is there any better way than this? BTW, @Sri.U , you could actually write this comment as an answer. You will definitely get some answer upvotes for that. Probably get chosen as a correct answer too.

Comment: thanks i will do that.

Comment: You can do the same thing using script. I have updated my answer

Comment: It should work. What happens when you try to ssh? What is the error message? Show us the entries in the routing table. I think your routing table is an issue here. The elastic IP traffic is not routed through the internet gateway. What is the output of traceroute and lft?

Comment: I think the answer by @michael-sqlbot is the best one so far. Following his answer, i was able to ssh to my app servers from my DevOps server using my app servers' PublicDNS rather than using their ElasticIPs directly. Using their PrivateDNS or PrivateIPs is out of the question because they will change every time an instance is replaced by a new one - the ElasticIPs and, hence, the PublicDNS would remain the same. I didn't have to change anything in the RouteTables or anything. I have only tried with SSH so far. I will do some more testing before i can accept his answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the IP addresses' hostnames, instead of IP addresses directly, because VPC does some magical mapping for you.

Take this elastic IP for example:

```
$ nslookup 203.0.113.50

50.113.0.203.in-addr.arpa       name = ec2-203-0-113-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

From inside the same VPC, this hostname does not resolve back to the elastic IP.  Instead, it resolves to the private IP.

```
$ nslookup  ec2-203-0-113-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

Name:   ec2-203-0-113-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
Address: 172.31.10.25 # returns the private IP of the attached instance
```

Yet from outside the VPC, it resolves more like you would expect:

```
$ nslookup ec2-203-0-113-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

Name:   ec2-203-0-113-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
Address: 203.0.113.50 # returns the elastic IP
```

By extension, then, if you were to configure a DNS `CNAME` devops.example.com pointing to the hostname of the elastic address of the devops machine, you'd get the external IP if you accessed it externally, but the internal IP if you accessed it internally.

Since internal requests would use the private IPs, no unusual security group configuration is needed.

Additional motivation: you pay for the traffic to leave your VPC and come back if you configure your instances to communicate using Elastic IPs within the same availability zone, $0.01/GB each direction, but not when using private IPs.  See [data transfer pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).  Presumably the difference is because you're using more of the AWS network hardware to translate and retranslate the traffic, which traverses the Internet Gateway twice when you use elastic IPs.

<sup>The example above is a real example from my network, with my EIP replaced with a placeholder from [RFC-5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737).</sup>

Comment: using the Public DNS instead of the Elastic IP solved the problem. When accessed from inside the VPC, the public DNS routes to a private internal IP address. When accessed from outside the VPC, the public DNS routes to the public Elastic IP address. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1) you can manually add inbound rules for SG2 like: 1) AllPorts EIP1 2) AllPorts EIP2

2) Do the same with script as below:

Make your script get the instances in a security group using the aws cli or API. 
Example:
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=instance.group-name,Values=SG2"

this will get all the instances in secuirty group SG2. Save the instance ids in a dict called SG2_Instances.

Then run:  aws ec2 describe-addresses.
This will give for each elastic ip, the corresponding fields including the instances ids if associated. Put all the instance ids along with EIP in a list. The list will look like:
[(EIP1, instanceId1), (EIP2,InstanceId2),..].
Now iterate through the list and check whether the instanceId in list is present in your dict SG2_Instances. If yes, then you can add a rule like mentioned in 1) using the corresponding EIP.